# Composite Overlay with Mini Magick and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minimagick

I have been trying to overlay one image on top of another and running into issues.

Only the first image is shown after the methods run. I can't figure out why.

```
version :final_product do
 process :frame_photo
end


def frame_photo
  second_image = MiniMagick::Image.open("http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/luminoto-modal/4x5-cream-blue.jpg")
  manipulate! do |img|
    result = img.composite(second_image) do |c|
      c.compose "Over"    # OverCompositeOp
      c.gravity "Center" # copy second_image onto first_image from (20, 20)
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: I just figured it out.  Looks like the image passed into the composite mehod is the background image.  I had to swith up this line to make it work       result = second_image.composite(img) do |c|